# How to work on map created by using arcgisUtils.createMap

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

```
 arcgisUtils.createMap(id,"map").then(function(response){
          //update the app 
          dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
          dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

          map = response.map;


        });
```

Comment: I need to access this map which is assigned to response.map outside the scope of then fucntion , please help

Comment: just declare 'var map;' outside the callback

Comment: Hi John , I have already declared a global var map , but when I try to add a new feature layer to map it does not work .

Comment: please supply a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather about your responses, it looks like you're trying to do things to the map before it is ready. You need to test whether the map has loaded its first layer before you can add your feature layers, etc. Here's how I would go about working with it.

```
var map;

function onMapLoad() {
  // when function called, do whatever you need to do to your map
  var flayer = new FeatureLayer(...);
  map.addLayer(flayer);
  // do other stuff...
}

arcgisUtils.createMap(id,"map").then(function(response){
  //update the app 
  dom.byId("title").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.title;
  dom.byId("subtitle").innerHTML = response.itemInfo.item.snippet;

   map = response.map;

   // check if map has loaded before manipulating it.
   if (map.loaded) {
     onMapLoad();
   } else {
     map.on("load", onMapLoad);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access it globally, one option is to set it this way

```
window.theMap = response.map;
```

Then you can call theMap or window.theMap from anywhere.

Comment: Hi Aamir, I tried using window.map it is not working, map itself is not rendered

Comment: I have renamed map to theMap to avoid conflict with the dom. You should try to access theMap only after it is initialized. What error do you see when adding a FeatureLayer

Answer (score -1):

```
var mymap;
 arcgisUtils.createMap(id,"map").then(function(response){
mymap = response.map;
```

Comment: please explain why this answers the question or what it fixes. We prefer long answers